# chosen multi select with required field not working

Tags: php, moodle, jquery-chosen, required

I'm using moodle and chosen and I have a select that has 'multiple' and 'required' set to true. If the user doesn't select anything, I don't see the error message. If I remove

```
$("#id_employeeSelect").chosen();
```

the required rule works. I searched online and read that chosen sets the style = display:none. But where do I go to make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because chosen is hidding the select and recreating it to have another functionality. You will have to do the validation in javascript (also, don't forget about the server side validation).

Comment: @BinarWeb Thank you for your reply. I already have server side validation. But because Im using moodle, I dont want to change moodle's form validation (and frankly, I'm not exactly sure where to update it to make my thing work).

Comment: You should also post more about what you are trying to modify (the form, javascript and everything related)